# % sign in front of dates in Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting percent signs in front of all of my pages that display dates. For example:

```
%04/%06/%2015
```

I'm not too sure why this is the case. At first I thought it may have been an issue with pytz, but it seems like this is not causing the problem.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good chance you're using `%` in the [`date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date). Somewhat confusingly, the format specifier in Django's `date` filter does *not* use percent signs.

Comment: Interesting. I've kept % in settings.py in the past and I didn't have this issue. In any case, removing the % from the filter fixes the issue. Thanks!